# What's special about a const @"SomeString"?

Tags: objective-c

Example:

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString * const NSLocalNotificationCenterType;
```

What is changed through that type qualifier? I understood it, if `const` was *in front of the asterisk.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `const` after the `*` means that the pointer itself is constant.  That is, you can't do

```
NSString *myString = @"abcde";
NSLocalNotificationCenterType = myString;
```